# How to move the output of a wordpress plugin

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, plugins

What I want to do is to move the content generated by a wordpress plugin to another part of the page. The plugin is "Tweet, Like, Share and Google +1". It basically allows you to easily insert the standard share buttons(Tweet, g+, like, share..) in your posts.

In it's control panel I can decide whether to display it on top of the post, on the bottom of the post or both. The thing is that the template I am using has a specific section designed to embed these sharing options (share_box div) and therefore, I would like to display the buttons there.

This is what I have:
[image: what i have]

And this is what I want:
[image: what i want]

I have no experience with editing plugins but I would be able to do this task myself if some sort of code for these buttons was provided.

If I go to plugins > editor and select this plugin, I can edit the plugin file - "only-tweet-like-share-and-google-1/tweet-like-plusone.php".

As it's probably necessary to take a look at it I pasted it here - http://pastebin.com/jNecxvtT

How can I make the plugin output its content to the share_box div?

Thanks you :)

Answer (score 0):

I'll help you get going.  The plugin is using a Wordpress filter hook to automatically append the output it creates to the end of each post.  The filter hook is;

```
add_filter('the_content', 'disp_social',1);
```

So it runs the method `disp_social()` and applies the returned content to the end of your post.

You would modify the $content that is passed in as an argument so that it's wrapped in markup that allows you to style it.  In the case below I've wrapped it in a div with the class `social_div`.  If you keep the variable name the same then the `return $content` that appears in various places doesn't need to change.

```
function disp_social($content) {

   $oldcontent = $content;
   $content = '<div class="social_div">'. $oldcontent .'</div>';

}
```

Comment: I was able to understand how the content was output but how exactly can I edit $content? I need to make the plugin output the social-box in between the share_box div tags, which is in the middle of code. Thank you for your time.

Comment: OK, I've updated the answer, hopefully that'll help you get going.

Comment: By using your updated code, I just get the article put in between the solid gray lines you can see in my pictures (the ones that act as separators) and the social buttons after it. Any thoughts?